# Evaluating $\arctan(-10)$

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering, how could I find the exact value of $\arctan(-10)$ ? We know that an approximation of the exact value would be $\arctan(-10)\approx-1.47112$ rad but if we wanted the exact value in radians, How would I find it ?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think there is a closed-form expression for this value?

Comment: Well, how do you know if there is one or not?

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the exact value from the Taylor series at $-\infty$ which is 
$$
\begin{align}
\arctan x&=-\frac\pi2-\frac1x+{1\over 3 x^3}-{1\over 5 x^5}+O(\frac1{x^7})\\
&=-\frac\pi2+\frac1{10}-{1\over 3,000}+{1\over 500,000}+O(\frac{1}{10^7})\\
&=-1.4711\dots
\end{align}
$$
This is obtained from the Taylor series at 0, $\arctan x=x-x^3/3+x^5/5+\cdots$ by using $\arctan(-1/x)$. There is no end to the terms, there is an infinite number of terms of the form
$$
(-1)^{n/2}{1\over(2n-1)x^{2n}}
$$

You can calculate numerically as accurately as you want to. Here is a computer program which does it:

```
package main

import (
    "math"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    max := 9
    x := -10.0
    a := -math.Pi/2.0
    sign := -1
    for i := 1; i < max; i += 2 {
        v := float64(sign)/(float64(i)*math.Pow(x, float64(i)))
        a += v
        sign *= -1
    }
    fmt.Printf ("%g %g %g\n", a, math.Tan(a), math.Atan(x))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no known closed form expressions for $\arctan(n\in\mathbb Z)$ other than for $n=0,\pm1$. For the numerical expression, see [OEIS A$195789$](http://oeis.org/A195789).

Comment: How do you determine if there is a closed form for arcsin, arccos etc. ?

Comment: @Astroman: We don't. It is an open question.

Answer (score 1):

Awww, this is an easy one.

First, I drew a green right triangle (with a $\color{green}{\text{crayon}}$) with a base of 1 and a height of -10. Then I measured the hypotenuse (of the $\color{green}{\text{triangle}}$) and used that length as the radius of a circle that I drew around it (with another $\color{red}{\text{crayon}}$). Then I drew a horizontal line with a 3rd $\color{darkorange}{\text{crayon}}$. Next, with a piece of $\color{blue}{\text{string}}$ I measured the $\color{red}{\text{arc length}}$ from the $\color{darkorange}{\text{horizontal line}}$ to the end of the $\color{green}{\text{hypotenuse}}$. Finally I divided that length by the radius of the circle.
[image]

My final answer was $-1.5$. :)

Answer (score 0):

We could cheat and use a complex logarithm...
$$
\arctan(-10) = \frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{-99+20i}{101}\right)
$$

Comment: I don't know complex logarithm... work only with the reals...